# Complex Excel "IF-THEN" Theory

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a complex Excel theory question concerning the limitations of the IF function.  I have 4 columns (3 columns to enter values and 1 to output the results).

[image: If-Then Conditional]

At this point, I just need to know if this is possible through nested IF functions (or a combination of IF and Match and Index) or if VBA would be better.  My worry is that I will waste all day trying to do something that is not even possible or spend the day going about it the wrong, and impractical, way.

Comment: VBA would probably be the easiest if you can Programm. You could do it with Nested IF functions but thats

Comment: Is that the exact output you want, including the ampersands? This is very simple.

Comment: The values in column A:C would be different (not always an "x" in the column), but the output is the same, including the ampersands.

Comment: Agreed, play with =REPT()&REPT()&REPT(), I think you could get some good miles out of it, without IFs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
=MID(REPT(" & "&A$1,A2="x")&REPT(" & "&B$1,B2="x")&REPT(" & "&C$1,C2="x"),4,999)
```

Enter the above formula into cell D2 and copy downward.

Note: this is completely generic and uses the column headers in row 1 for the output.

Answer (score 0):

For this case you can use

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(IF(A1="x","Col 1 & ","") & 
              IF(B1="x","Col 2 & ","") & 
              IF(C1="x","Col 3 & ",""),
              COUNTIF(A1:C1,"x")*8-3), "")
```

It basically generates all the Col n fields with the ampersand.
Then it calculates the generated string (because here all have equal length) and cuts off the last three chracters which will always be `&` unless all values are `-`, then it puts nothing (because it would call `=LEFT("", -3)` otherwise.

For a more generic formula supporting variable lengths per column you'd have to calculate the length added to the output manually for each cell.

Answer (score 0):

VBA solution if you want to go that way:

```
Function RangeResults(rng As Excel.Range) As String

Dim output As String

    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If cell.Row = rng.Cells(1).Row Then
            output = output & IIf(UCase(cell.Value) = "X", "Col " & cell.Column & " & ", vbNullString)
        End If
    Next

    If Len(output) > 0 Then
        output = Left(output, Len(output) - 3)
    End If

    RangeResults = output

End Function
```

Then in col D just use `=RangeResults(A2:C2)` and drag down as needed